# Laravel view not displaying long number correctly

Tags: laravel-4

I have a column name xxx in database. it is of type `varchar(255)`. It is storing `9006686769394`. I access its value and store it in a variable named `$refCode`. When I do {{ $refCode }} in laravel view, it displays like this: `9.00668676939E+12`. Why can't I display the variable properly ? Any suggestion ?

Comment: what does astr means @Digitlimit

Comment: You can trying casting `$refCode` to string before sending it to the view, like so `$refCode = (string) $refCode;`